# Use Resharper with the C language in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, resharper

I recently started studying at university which granted me a student license for all JetBrains products. I thought it would be an excellent chance to try Resharper for C# and C++. I am now taking a course in C.

From what I searched online, Visual Studio can work with C code. However, it seems that Resharper is only meant for C++ as it suggests warnings that only make sense in C++. For example, if I use something like `#define N 5`, Resharper suggests I use `constexpr` instead, which doesn't exist in C as far as I am aware.

Also, there are no options for Code Editing menu for C in Resharper's settings window, only for C++. This means I can't configure separate naming conventions for C and C++ for example. For example, I like the convention of `ALL_CAPS` for enum constants in C, since they live in the global namespace. In C++, however, I can use `enum class` so enum constants live in the enum's namespace and I can be more flexible and use `PascalCase` for instance.

Is there a way to configure Resharper to work with C? Or at least configure it not to display inspections specific for C++ in C files?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and ReSharper sounds like a static code analyzer for C#, which is yet another language. What does your research in ReSharper's documentation reveal? Did you ask JetBrain about this? What did they say?

Comment: Resharper also supports C++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this is a Visual Studio inspection and not a ReSharper one. Disabling Visual Studio IntelliSense via `Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Advanced | Browsing/Navigation | Disable Database` solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper supports the C language. When a file uses C, C++-specific code checks should get disabled in that file. If you see C++-specific suggestions in a C file, file an issue or let JetBrains know via "ReSharper | Help | Report a bug".

It does not make a lot of sense to add separate settings for the C language since they are mostly the same as for C++. Regarding naming conventions, you can configure separate rules for members of `enum` and `enum class` if you want to. You can also create custom naming conventions for your C project and save them to project settings.

Comment: I sent a bug report to JetBrains. I also used your suggestion to make separate conventions for `enum` and `enum class` members